# mysql if exist variable

Tags: mysql, variables

**TABLES**:

`cart`, `order`, `customer`

**ID**:

`id_cart`, `date_add`, `id_customer` FROM `cart`

`firstname`, `lastname` FROM `customer`

**and I need to get data**:

`Firstname`, `Lastname`, `Date_add`, `id_Cart`, BUT `id_Cart` have not exist on `ORDER` table.

So if `id_cart` in `CART` table not exist on `ORDER` table I get data: `id_Cart`, `date_add`, `id_customer`

---

```
$sql = '
SELECT cu.firstname, cu.lastname, ca.date_add, ca.id_cart
  FROM ps_cart ca
  JOIN ps_customer cu
    ON ca.id_customer = cu.id_customer
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
     FROM `ps_orders` o
    WHERE o.id_cart = ca.id_cart
       )';


$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $handle );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM))
{
    echo 
         "Name :{$row['firstname']}   ".
         "Lastname : {$row['lastname']}  ".
         "Date_add : {$row['date_add']}  ".
         "CART_ID : {$row['id_cart']}  ".

         "--------------------------------<br>";
}
mysql_free_result($retval);
echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
mysql_close($handle);
```

This is my code. It seems your query is what I need but I got such result: Name: Lastname: Date_add: CART_ID and lot of lines but where is data? No errors..

Comment: ...what?I understand you might not be fluent in english, in that case please present it in a universally understood way...make a sql fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Mh I used your code but I got all data even if id_cart not exist on ps_orders table. I tryed to look if 23120 ID exist in ps_orders table and this ID not exist, but I got it in result page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna take a wild stab in the dark here:

```
SELECT cu.firstname, cu.lastname, ca.date_add, ca.id_cart
  FROM ps_cart ca
  JOIN ps_customer cu
    ON ca.id_customer = cu.id_customer
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
     FROM ps_orders o
    WHERE o.id_cart = ca.id_cart
       )';
```

Change the `MYSQL_NUM` to `MYSQL_ASSOC` to be able to extract data using `$row['column_name']`